# Layout shrinks content when showing Snackbar

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, fullscreen, snackbar

I'm using a Unity/Vuforia view in an app, when showing a native Snackbar the whole content shrinks for a bit and stays that way.

My first thought was that it had something to do with the fact that unity/Vuforia sets the activity as 'Fullscreen', disabling that did not work as the issue still remains.

The Content before the snackbar has been shown
[image]

After the snackbar
[image]

I noticed it has the same height of a Toolbar or the NavigationBars at the bottom. When playing around with the options to hide the Navigation Bars I noticed the changes won't stay. When trying to hide it all, it hides for a second and then after a 200 milliseconds show again.
I tried it with this code

```
        window.decorView.apply {
            // Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
            // SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
            // a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
            // hide the navigation bar.
            systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I fixed it was by enabling the Fullscreen option in Vuforia, it was not what we desired, but it was the quickest solution.